# Excel count unique with a condition

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the below table and need to find a formula to count the unique instances in column B in relation to the months in column A:

```
MonthBooked Concatenation
Jun-14  JSM010414BookShopInc.RenewalBooks
Jun-14  JSM010414BookShopInc.NewBooksNew(Location)Mall
Jun-14  JSM010414BookShopInc.NewBooksNew(Location)Mall
Jun-14  JSM010414BookShopInc.NewBooksNew(Location)HighStreet
Dec-14  BCO121214BookShopInc.NewMagazinesBrandNew
Dec-14  BCO311214BookShopInc.NewPampletBrandNew
Jun-15  JSM010415BookShopInc.RenewalBooks
Dec-15  BookShopInc.Magazines
Dec-15  BookShopInc.Pamplet
```

I've seen similar questions on this fine website but nothing that either provides the solution or something that I can adapt to get there.

I've tried

```
{=SUM(IF($A$2:$A$10=A16,1/COUNTIF($B$2:$B$10,$B$2:$B$10)))}
```

(where A16 = a cell populated with 'Jun-14') but it doesn't react correctly to changes in the data.  Am I on the right lines here or is a different approach required?

Thanks in advance!

Al

Comment: What is the desired result? Your formula results in 3 with your data. Why is that not right?

Comment: Although the result is correct for the example given the quoted formula doesn't work correctly if any of the column B texts are repeated in another month as well as the month of interest, e.g. if you change the 2nd date down (A3) to Jul-14 the result is now 2.5 which obviously isn't correct - my suggested Answer should work in all circumstances

Comment: Sure, but the question was not clear about this. Now it is.

Answer (score 1):

For consistent results use this approach

`=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF($A$2:$A$10=A16,IF($B$2:$B$10<>"",MATCH($B$2:$B$10,$B$2:$B$10,0))),ROW($B$2:$B$10)-ROW($B$2)+1),1))`

confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>